# Unable to start an audio player

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have an audio player and it won't play the sound, has someone any idea why?
And i have imported AVFoundationFramework.h

This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"begin" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
}
```

Comment: if you actually *looked* at the error returned by AVAudioPlayer's error parameter (instead of passing "nil" to it) you might have a useful hint to work with.

Comment: Have you tried using avplayer instead of avaudioplayer?  That's how I'm playing audio in my apps.  May be a bad suggestion, but if it gets it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate:

```
 [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
```

and make sure your volume is correctly set.

Comment: is your [audioPlayer play] written after the settings, or inside as we can see here?